# Element wise multiplication using Numpy [Python]

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to get the element-wise mulitplication using normal *, and i tried np.multiply(), both give a weird answers.

now (1-y) is (100,) and np.log(1-sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta)))) is (100,1), so when i muliply them by element-wise, it should give (100,1); but it gives me (100,100) matrix(ALL are higlighted BLUE)

[image]

Here is my original function if it can help.
[image]

Can anyone help me with getting the source of erre here?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: By the rules of `broadcasting` a (100,) expands to (1,100).  That with a (100,1) produces a (100,100).  You'll be forever frustrated in numpy if you don't learn those basics.

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why python does this, but the way to solve it would be to apply `np.reshape((1-y),(100,1))` and then apply `np.multiply()`. In general it's always better to reshape your arrays and to give them a second dimension.

**EDIT**: [This](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:%7E:text=The%20term%20broadcasting%20describes%20how,different%20shapes%20during%20arithmetic%20operations.&text=Broadcasting%20provides%20a%20means%20of,in%20C%20instead%20of%20Python.) explains how numpy does the broadcasting when using an array of dimensions `(n,)` and `(n,1)`.

Comment: those are the basic rules of numpy broardcasting.

Comment: Yes it solved it. Thanks so much